# Has the Punisher ever tried to kill superheroes that were once criminals like Hawkeye or Black Widow?

Tags: marvel, avengers, the-punisher

So the Punisher is pretty well known within Marvel comics and comics in general for his willingness to kill, draconian sense of morality, and rather black-and-white view of good and evil. He has a strict code against harming those he deems "innocent", but he's also very big on "no atonement, no forgiveness", given he's been known to kill supervillains who try to switch sides (e.g., during *Civil War*). He's normally depicted as someone who, unlike the other Marvel heroes that kill (e.g., Wolverine, Black Widow, etc.), doesn't really have an off switch: you can't negotiate with him, he doesn't spare people he deems "bad", and once he labels someone as such he can't be talked out of trying to kill them.

This actually raises an interesting question, **has *The Punisher* ever tried to kill any of the Marvel superheroes who used to be criminals or supervillains at some point in their lives**? Like, not the heroes like Wolverine who kill people but could still be framed as "good" under Castle's sense of morality, or Venom who is depicted as "reformed but not *that* reformed", the Marvel heroes who *were* villains but for whom their villain days are like a bad memory.

I'm specifically thinking of Hawkeye and Black Widow. Both characters were originally introduced as villains that became good guys and stayed good guys, and this does influence aspects of their characterization to this day. Hawkeye was introduced as a member of the Circus of Crime, and Black Widow was an *Iron Man* villain for several encounters before she revamped her image as a good guy. The whole "I used to be a bad guy and I'm trying to make up for it" is said to be more prominent for the MCU version of Black Widow, but it still comes up in the comics. However, this "once a villain" backstory also applies to a number of less known Marvel heroes, like Hobie Brown/The Prowler. The Hulk has also accused of breaking the law from time to time, and Quicksilver, Scarlet Witch, The Vision started out as supervillains. So did Namor but...it's Namor. The number of Avengers that used to be ex-supervillains has even been joked about in the comics.

**Has the comics ever addressed this?** The relationship between the Punisher and other superheroes like the Avengers is usually depicted as "other heroes criticize Castle, he ignores them and storms off", but it rarely escalates beyond that. However, given the Punisher's worldview shouldn't the Punisher and Avengers not even be on civil speaking terms, because Castle would immediately try to murder two core members (Hawkeye and Black Widow) and as much as half the team (plus Scarlet Witch, Quicksilver, Vision, and possibly Hulk) because of his black-and-white sense of morality and sense of "no forgiveness".

I tried looking to see if this question came up in the comics, but I couldn't find any reference to Marvel Comics even touching on this at all. Not even some scene where the Punisher gives some excuse as to why he's turning a blind eye to the heroes that used to be villains to explain why Marvel's stable of heroes isn't actively trying to kill each other? I know in his first introduction in *Amazing Spider-Man* #129 he tries to kill the innocent Spider-Man, but that turns out to be a case of mistaken identity due to the Jackal and JJJ's general smear campaign. I know in his team-up with Venom/Anti-Venom he tells Eddie Brock if he steps one toe out of line he'll try to shoot him, but that's Venom and even at his most heroic Venom/Anti-Venom still often eats people and can still easily be perceived as "bad guy" in Castle's mind. I've never seen anything from Marvel addressing how the Punisher treats people who've had a straightforward Heel-Face Turn.

Comment: This is Marvel. Everyone has tried to kill everyone multiple times, as well as each individual attempting to kill their own time travel duplicates and alternate universe doubles

Comment: I would assume we're ignoring the time he tried to kill everyone in the Marvel Universe; https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/25761388-punisher-kills-the-marvel-universe-1

Comment: @Valorum tried? I thought he succeeded in killing almost all of them.

Comment: @Shreedhar - Spoilers!

Comment: He tries to kill her here. They're not evenly matched. She clearly has all kinds of advantages over him in terms of speed, agility, etc; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PijpwlmY4AI

Comment: I think it would be hard to find any for Hawkeye. He was a villain for like 5 minutes, and all just to impress Black Widow. He messed around a bit with Iron Man, and that was it. Iron Man then instantly forgave him when he realized Hawkeye wanted to do good. Punisher prefers to go after more clear-cut villains than that.

Comment: @user2352714 - Are you primarily interested in whether Castle has tried to kill Hawkeye and Black Widow specifically, or what his attitude is towards criminals-turned-heroes in general? If it's the latter, I think you should edit the title of this question, as it's somewhat misleading.

Comment: @Valorum I would say yes, because in that case Punisher's motivation was entirely different (hatred of superheroes versus hatred of criminals). This isn't a question of whether he could fight them but if the comics ever addressed that based on his established character traits he doesn't have a reason not to.